# Pyspark: overwriting an empy dataframe should delete previous files

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

my beloved data engineers,

I Have a path under which there is some data from a previous run representing a dataframe.

I run a job that is supposed to overwrite this path with a new dataframe. This new dataframe is empty (and this is totally normal). But when I write it to the destination where are the previous files, those files are not deleted, as if the new empty dataframe was not saved at all and Sparks was too lazy to do so.

Steps to reproduce:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from os import walk

session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType()), StructField("value", StringType())])
destination_path = "/tmp/filled_df/"

# Filled dataframe
data = [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
filled_df = session.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(schema)
filled_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(destination_path)
print("Filled dataframe", next(walk(destination_path), (None, None, []))[2])
## prints: "Filled dataframe    ['part-00000-xxx.parquet']

# Empty dataframe
empty_df = session.sparkContext.emptyRDD().toDF(schema)
empty_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(destination_path)
print("Empty dataframe", next(walk(destination_path), (None, None, []))[2])
## prints: "Empty dataframe    ['part-00000-xxx.parquet']"
## but should prints: "Empty dataframe    []"
```

**How could I force Spark to write an empty dataframe removing all previous files in the destination?**

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK empty (devoid of rows) parquet file is not zero-length, it still contains meta/schema information. Perhaps you can try reading your destination path and do a count, or just use `parquet-tools` to inspect `part-00000-xxx.parquet` directly. +1 for beloved :)

Comment: Ok, my reproducer does not enlight the bug correctly

Comment: Your code works fine, it generate an empty dataframe, some empty files are generated though (metadata) even when your dataframe is empty, to make sure if it's empty or not print a count at the end of each write: "session.read.parquet(destination_path).count()"